# How to present a command in multiple lines for instant copy/paste usage?

Tags: shell, command-line, clipboard, newlines, text-formatting

I am documenting some commands for future usage, some of them are too long and I want to document them in multiple lines for visualization, and then just copy and paste them for usage. For example:

Raw:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in intermediate/certs/lala-lira.cert.pem -inkey intermediate/private/lala-lira.key.pem -out intermediate/private/lala-lira.pfx
```

Presentational:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export
-in intermediate/certs/lala-lira.cert.pem
-inkey intermediate/private/lala-lira.key.pem
-out intermediate/private/lala-lira.pfx
```

The problem is if I copy and paste the presentational form, each line will be interpreted as one individual and independent command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

End every line but for the last with a backslash.  To use your command as an example:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export \
-in intermediate/certs/lala-lira.cert.pem \
-inkey intermediate/private/lala-lira.key.pem \
-out intermediate/private/lala-lira.pfx
```

What you are doing here is escaping the end-of-line, causing the shell to treat is as non-delimiting whitespace.  Since the escape marker only has an effect upon the next character, the next character *must* be the end-of-line.  (That means no trailing spaces allowed; beware!)

Comment: A bit of personal preference, but you might consider putting a trailing backslash on all lines of the command, and then a semicolon as the final line. Much like trailing commas in other languages, it makes it more easily extensible…but more importantly it looks prettier to me. :-)

Comment: While I can admire the aesthetic sense, this means _more_ editing, and not _less_, if you decide to add more at the end of the command (admittedly, 'more' consists of removing the semicolon).

Comment: One of us misunderstands—I'm suggesting [this](https://gist.github.com/wchargin/c1bd7b31ba964fcb306bff9683ffb0f3), such that adding the flag `--quux` simply requires adding a line containing "--quux <backslash>".

Comment: Ah, I get ya.  Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function (or shell script) that wraps the text and assigns the backslashes:

```
function wrapit { fmt -s -w 50 - | sed '$!s/$/ \\/'; }
```

This uses the [fmt tool](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fmt) to wrap the text to 50 characters (adjust as you see fit). It also tells `fmt` to (`s`) split only, so that it won't join any short lines in the input. It then uses sed to add backslashes to every line except the last one:

- `$` is the address of the last line in the file
- `!` means apply the subsequent command on lines that do *not* match the given address (here, all but the last line)
- `s/$/ \\/` says to replace the "end of the line" (`$`) with a space and a backslash, where the backslash needs to be escaped in order to finally appear as a single backslash.

Either pipe text to this function/script or execute the script then enter text then end the text with Control-D:

```
echo "openssl pkcs12 -export -in intermediate/certs/lala-lira.cert.pem -inkey intermediate/private/lala-lira.key.pem -out intermediate/private/lala-lira.pfx" | wrapit
```

or

```
$ wrapit
openssl pkcs12 -export -in intermediate/certs/lala-lira.cert.pem -inkey intermediate/private/lala-lira.key.pem -out intermediate/private/lala-lira.pfx
```

<kbd>Control-D</kbd>

This is a simplistic script -- it does not understand command options or quotation marks; it would turn your example input into:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in \
intermediate/certs/lala-lira.cert.pem -inkey \
intermediate/private/lala-lira.key.pem -out \
intermediate/private/lala-lira.pfx
```

but I wanted to present a generic answer in case you wanted a scripted solution for many various inputs.